# Is it possible to create a MS Teams App incl. messaging extension without an Azure Bot?

Tags: azure, bots, microsoft-teams

I am building a Teams App which uses a search based messaging extension. As far as I understand, I need a bot for this, because the bot is basically posting the adaptive card created from the data on my external webapp to the chat.

Is it possible to create or host a bot somewhere else than in Azure? I do not have an Azure subscription. If so, how would I go about using a different Bot for my Teams App?

Thanks for helping in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teams bots rely on the underlying Microsoft Bot Framework - the same engine for building any kinds of bots in the Microsoft ecosystem (e.g. slack or web or facebook bots). The only way to register those bots in MS Bot Framework is, yes, via the Azure portal. *However*, you don't need to HOST your bot in Azure - the physical web endpoint can live anywhere that's publicly httpS addressable (e.g. AWS), as long as the *registration* for the bot is in Azure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Got some follow up questions though. I guess first of all, and sorry if its a noob question, since I am new to Azure and Teams and bot networks - Do I need an Azure subscription in order to register the bot in Azure? Just asking because some of the features seem to be free of charge, just not sure if that is one of them. Want to make sure before I pay for it. Second question: what exactly is the role of a bot in this? Is it just code that executes something, as you say, I can host it (and thus write the code for it in AWS as well? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you will need a subscription, and that might even mean you need to -register- a credit card as a payment option for anything that you might use that's billable in future. However, what you need here, this kind of bot registration, would be free for a fairly large amount of calls to the bot. When you set it up, just be sure to change the correct option

Comment: it's just a single setup screen, so it's hard to miss, but it defaults to "standard" and you can change it to "free". Free gives you 10000 calls a month to your bot, or something like that. Over that limit, Microsoft does charge a monthly fee

Comment: With regards the role of the Bot, that's just how this functionality in Teams is built - it assumes that there's a bot powering the message extension.

Answer (score 0):

- yes, you can create the Bot framework locally and run it using Visual Studio.
- To debug Bot locally in teams you need to use a tunneling service like `ngrok`.
- To install `ngrok` run the following command.

```html
    ngrok http <port> -host-header=localhost:<port>
```

- Here is [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-create-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp,vs) related Bot framework running locally and the installation steps for [ngrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/debug/locally-with-an-ide).

Comment: Thank you for your answer - as far as I understand, this is for debugging or "local" purposes only? I want to publish the app on the teams store later on. In the documentation you linked to create the Bot locally, it says as a next step to "deploy your bot to Azure" which basically is the same problem I already had - I do not have an Azure account. Maybe I should have asked in the first place - do I need an Azure account to create a teams app incl. messaging extension so I can publish it to the teams app store?

Comment: yes, you need an Azure account to publish Bot services